# Is there any way where I can set user information into Session values from cookies while rendering a controller in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller

I have tried in `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var cookiesDataUserinfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserInfo"];
                if (cookiesDataUserinfo != null)
                {
                    Session["UserId"] = cookiesDataUserinfo["UserId"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

But I am getting the error "Session state is not available in this context."
I also tried to load data from cookies in constructor of a controller. But cookies is null inside constructor.
Is there any way where I can set session values from cookies before any view is rendered in my MVC project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution I was looking for. I need to use the `Application_AcquireRequestState` method in `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var cookiesDataUserinfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserInfo"];
        if (cookiesDataUserinfo != null)
        {
            Session["UserId"] = cookiesDataUserinfo["UserId"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

For every request the `Application_AcquireRequestState`  method is called and  I can set session values from Cookies if available.